# Package Problems upgrading to Meteor 1.2, cannot start server now

Tags: meteor

I just upgraded to Meteor 1.2 from 1.1.

It did not upgrade and this is what it output

```
MacBook-Pro:ProjectX Nearpoint$ meteor update
Update to release METEOR@1.2.0.1 is impossible:                                    
While selecting package versions:             
error: Conflict: Constraint less@1.0.11 is not satisfied by less 2.5.0_2.
Constraints on package "less":
* less@=2.5.0_2 <- top level
* less@1.0.11 <- multiply:iron-router-progress 1.0.1
* less@1.0.0||2.0.0 <- matteodem:easy-search 1.6.3
* less@1.0.0||2.0.0 <- mdg:camera 1.1.5

This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your current package constraints.
npm-container: updating npm dependencies -- beagle, validator, async...

Changes to your project's package version selections from updating package versions:

cfs:http-methods             upgraded from 0.0.29 to 0.0.30
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3  upgraded from 1.2.79 to 1.2.80
matteodem:easy-search        upgraded from 1.6.3 to 1.6.4
meteorhacks:kadira           upgraded from 2.23.2 to 2.23.4


The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest version available:
 * kevohagan:sweetalert 0.5.0 (1.0.0 is available)
 * mdg:camera 1.1.5 (1.2.0 is available)      
 * natestrauser:filepicker-plus 1.2.3 (2.0.0 is available)
 * natestrauser:select2 3.5.1 (4.0.0_1 is available)
 * zimme:iron-router-active 1.0.4 (2.0.1 is available)

Newer versions of the following indirect dependencies are available:
 * babrahams:editable-json 0.4.3 (0.6.0 is available)
 * matb33:collection-hooks 0.7.15 (0.8.0 is available)
 * meteorhacks:aggregate 1.2.1 (1.3.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:hotreload 0.2.0 (0.3.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:listen 0.3.0 (0.4.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:pub 0.3.1 (0.4.0 is available)  
 * meteortoys:status 0.1.0 (0.2.0 is available)
 * meteortoys:toypro 0.4.2 (0.5.0 is available)
 * softwarerero:accounts-t9n 1.0.9 (1.1.4 is available)
 * tap:i18n 1.5.1 (1.6.1 is available)        
 * underscorestring:underscore.string 3.0.3_1 (3.2.2 is available)
To update one or more of these packages, pass their names to `meteor update`.
```

What should I do to fix this now? I currently cannot start my server after upgrading.

I am getting the error

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While selecting package versions:
   error: Potentially incompatible change required to top-level dependency: matteodem:easy-search 1.6.3,
   was 1.6.4.
   Constraints on package "matteodem:easy-search":

   To allow potentially incompatible changes to top-level dependencies, you must pass
   --allow-incompatible-update on the command line.

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

Comment: Am I supposed to upgrade each package manually by typing `meteor update packageName`

Comment: Ok So I am less confused now. What had happened is Meteor upgraded Easy Search to 1.6.4 which depended on Meteor 1.2. But it did not upgrade Meteor to version 1.2. Thus the error. Also overall I probably have to wait till multiply:iron-router-progress 1.0.1, and mdg:camera upgrades their dependencies

Comment: I have the same problem but at least in my case Meteor didn't upgrade to 1.2 as it had some constraints (no idea who set these constraints, I'm 5 weeks into using Meteor and this is my first update). Hope you will get a valid answer to your question soon